# ccmake automatically configure and generate

Tags: cmake

I've got a C++ project that uses cmake, and I'm trying to automate its build, but having to call the following puts me into a curses-style UI where I have press the 'C' key twice to configure and then 'G' to generate the Makefile:

```
$ ccmake .
```

Is there a way to configure and generate from the *CMakeLists.txt* file without the human input?

Comment: Building in-source is disadviced. Create a build folder and use `cmake ..` to get out-of-source-builds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `cmake .` which is the command line equivalent. If you want to adjust parameters, add `-D PARAMETER=VALUE` right before the path.